# Installing Android in Samsun Omnia M

Tags: installation

Can I install android on samsung omnia m mobile. Currently it is running on windows 7.5 mango. It has 4gb internal space..but no slot for micro sd card. If yes, then which version of android will be suitable for my device?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a very long process and it seems like it is very hard to reverse:

- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1040025

From what I read you need to be pretty tech savvy to get this to work. If you have Ubuntu installed then it is a little bit easier.

You need to know how to partition a hard drive and things like that, if you are not very Linux savvy I would probably give this one a pass. If you are very Linux savvy or you are just dying to have Android then I will help you through it, but it will be a lot of instructions and it will take a very long time. And as with any non-official Android port, there are a couple of weird problems with it, but it seems they can all be fixed with work arounds.

I hope this info helped you, let me know if you decide that you are dead set on getting Android on your device. I will try to give you some pointers to help you along the way.